# Can someone explain double recursion python?

Tags: python, recursion

Im trying to understand double recursion but i'm not getting anywhere.

```
def f(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    return f(s[1:]) + s[0]
print f('world')
```

> > > dlrow

if am right the above code will do the following:

1. f(s[1:]) + s[0] ==> f(orld) + w
2. f(s[1:]) + s[0] ==> f(rld) + o
3. f(s[1:]) + s[0] ==> f(ld) + r
4. f(s[1:]) + s[0] ==> f(d) + l <== here len(s) == 1 so s = d,

then:

4. d + l = dl
5. dl + r = dlr
6. dlr + o = dlro
7. dlro + w = dlrow

so dlrow will be printed as seen above.

I can not understand the code when you make it double recursive:

```
def f(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    else:
        return f(f(s[1:])) + s[0] #Note double recursion
print f('world')
```

Can someone please explain to me how this double recursion works?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? Why not try drawing the same diagram again?

Comment: The double recursion prints "orldw". the problem is, that i cannot draw a diagram for it..

Comment: You see how long your analysis of the original version is?  I assume the analysis of the second version will be twice as long ;-)

Comment: Princeton has this fantastic visualization of recursion using the Fibonacci sequence: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/

Comment: I suggest you start from the base case: what does calling the function on it twice do? Then build "out". Note that `y = f(f(x))` is `temp = f(x); y = f(temp)`.

Comment: I'd add a s*tload of `prints` too **:-D :-D** (no, seriously)

Comment: thanks guys for all your tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2019, using online compilers, such as www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler,
the print lines as above do not work.  Here is working code:

```
import inspect 

def f(s):
   print("  " * (len(inspect.stack())-2), '>>', s)
   if len(s) <= 1:
      print( "  " * (len(inspect.stack())-2), '<<', s)
      return s
   else:
      retval = f(f(s[1:])) + s[0] #Note double recursion
      print( "  " * (len(inspect.stack())-2), '<<', retval)
      return retval 


print(f('world'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easy way to instrument your recursive code

```
import inspect

def f(s):
    print "  " * (len(inspect.stack())-2), '>>', s
    if len(s) <= 1:
        print "  " * (len(inspect.stack())-2), '<<', s
        return s
    else:
        retval = f(f(s[1:])) + s[0] #Note double recursion
        print "  " * (len(inspect.stack())-2), '<<', retval
        return retval


print f('world')
```

prints

```
 >> world
   >> orld
     >> rld
       >> ld
         >> d
         << d
         >> d
         << d
       << dl
       >> dl
         >> l
         << l
         >> l
         << l
       << ld
     << ldr
     >> ldr
       >> dr
         >> r
         << r
         >> r
         << r
       << rd
       >> rd
         >> d
         << d
         >> d
         << d
       << dr
     << drl
   << drlo
   >> drlo
     >> rlo
       >> lo
         >> o
         << o
         >> o
         << o
       << ol
       >> ol
         >> l
         << l
         >> l
         << l
       << lo
     << lor
     >> lor
       >> or
         >> r
         << r
         >> r
         << r
       << ro
       >> ro
         >> o
         << o
         >> o
         << o
       << or
     << orl
   << orld
 << orldw
orldw
```

Comment: Thanks gribbler, i didn't know about inspect. everything becomes easier when visualized.

Comment: But the question "what does this function do" remains.  For "world" it returns "orld" + "w".  But for other lengths the returned value is more complex.  The most peculiar thing I just found out is that `f(f(f('123')))` returns `'123'`, `f(f(f(f('1234'))))` returns `'1234'` etc. for lengths up to 8.  But `f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f('123456789')))))))))` suddenly returns `'283145796'`.  This is most peculiar.

Comment: yes you're right! I was trying the same with "world". I have to play around with it, I will definitely come back to it after i understand what it does.

Comment: Good luck.  Seems to be a very complex topic.  Have a look at http://pastebin.com/7fbcXZFc where I tried around a little bit.